# Page contains error in android phonegap wit h jquery mobile. Please help me i m in real need

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have deployed android application made with phone gap, and I haven't problem with emulator and web browser.But when i install that application on android  tablet (samsung galaxy) device it shows following error when i click on cell of table.

```
Application Error: The web page contains an error. (file:///android_asset/www/tips_list.html?act=SET_TIPS_LIST&cid=1)
```

In my application I am displaying list of categories in table and when user click on any cell of table it will navigate to its subcategory page. It works fine in emulator but crashes in tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running into the following Android bugs:

1. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535
2. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327

Comment: The solution is don't depend on parameters. Use localStorage to pass data between pages.

Comment: hey hie simon, it's not an stand alone app.....every time the data goin to be updated...so can't use local data storage

Comment: Sure you can. This is the way many other people have fixed this issue using PhoneGap on Android.